# D3: Separating data exit/remove/merge from drawing of elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am drawing some complex interactive SVGs with D3 v4 and running into some problems. My goals are:

- Each data element corresponds to a group with multiple SVG shape elements (e.g. `<g><circle></circle><circle></circle></g>`)
- The multiple SVG shape elements have to be drawn in a certain order (because they overlap)
- Certain shape elements are updated without data elements being added or removed (e.g. when clicking on a shape, change the shape color)

I am running into trouble because the `.data()` -> `.exit().remove()` -> `.enter()` -> `.merge()` process requires a specific order and that order conflicts with the necessary draw order as well as the ability to update styles on the fly. This is what I started with, which does not work because of draw order:

```
function updateGraph() {
    let eachNodeG = allNodesG
        .selectAll('.eachNodeG')
        .data(graphData._nodes, function (d) {
            return d._id;
        })

    eachNodeG.exit().remove();

    let eachNodeGEnter = eachNodeG.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr("class", "eachNodeG")

    eachNodeGEnter
        .append('circle')
        .classed('interactivecircle', true)
        .on('click', function (d) {...})

    let eachNodeG = eachNodeGEnter
        .merge(eachNodeG)
        .style('fill', function (d) {...}) //this is here b/c it needs to change
            // when data change (without them being added/removed)

    // this must be separate because the background circle needs to change even
    // when nodes are not added and removed; but this doesn't work here because
    // the circle needs to be in the background
    eachNodeG
        .append('circle')
        .classed('bgcircle', true)
}
```

I thought maybe I could separate the data update process from the data drawing process entirely, by doing `enter() exit() merge()` just on the groups containing the data and then drawing everything afterward. But here I run into a different problem: either I remove and re-add all of the shapes on every update (which makes double-clicking difficult and seems like a waste of processing power), or I have to figure out some way to update only the shapes that have changed. Does it using the remove and re-add method looks like this:

```
// add/remove individual groups based on updated data
let eachNodeG = allNodesG
    .selectAll('.eachNodeG')
    .data(graphData._nodes)

eachNodeG.exit().remove();

let eachNodeGEnter = eachNodeG.enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr("class", "eachNodeG")

eachNodeG = eachNodeGEnter
    .merge(eachNodeG)

// draw (or remove and re-draw) elements within individual groups
d3.selectAll('.bgcircle').remove()

eachNodeG.append('circle')
    .classed('bgcircle', true)

d3.selectAll('.interactivecircle').remove()

eachNodeG.append('circle')
    .classed('interactivecircle', true)
    .style('fill', function (d) {...})
    .on('click',function(d){...})
})
```

Is there a better way to draw the shapes in order while keeping them updateable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [selection.raise](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_raise) or [selection.lower](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_lower) to move circles after they have been created.

Comment: I know I've seen those functions before, how I forgot about them is beyond me. Thanks!